# JSF reset text field

Tags: jsf

I want to reset text field on click of the reset button. How can I do it in JSF?

Answer (score 2):

Well, then make an `<input type="reset">` and if you have a `<h:form>` it will work. If you want to clear an individual field, use javascript.

Comment: I use <h:commandButton  > how is it possible text box blank

Comment: @vivek - don't use commandButton. There is no need for it if you only want a reset button

Comment: reset value but give again previous value

Comment: @vivek that's not reset. That's undo. See http://www.google.com/search?hl=&q=javascript+undo&sourceid=navclient-ff&rlz=1B3GGLL_en-GB___GB382&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

You can reset your form in JSF using

```
<h:commandButton type="reset" value="Reset" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an action to rest all fields that you want to rest:

```
<h:commandButton value="Reset" action="#{myBean.reset}" render="formId" />
```

and

```
public void rest() {

  setField1(null);
  setList1(null);
  setField2(null);
}
```

Comment: Bad formatting too