# Blank a text field on click of a button

Tags: java, jsf

How to blank a text field on click of a button in JSF?

Comment: You've already asked this before: [JSF reset text field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266132/jsf-reset-text-field). You should have edited the question to clarify the requirement more.

Answer (score 0):

use [f:ajax](http://www.jairrillo.com/blog/2009/10/10/jsf-20-and-ajax-example/)

Your text field is obviosly binded to some property in backing bean. You can call the method of backing bean, which will null the appropriate property. Specifying the f:ajax tag, you will mention what action should be called and what ui component will be updated.

Comment: That only works when the OP is using JSF 2.0. The OP didn't mention the JSF version at all.

Answer (score 0):

----->>>  JSPX File

< ice:inputText id="nameId"
                  value="#{createBrandBean.brand.name}"
                  size="30" maxlength="40" tabindex="2" 
                  onkeydown="moveFocus(event, 'aliasId')"
                />

< ice:commandButton value="Save" id="saveButton" 
                  action="#{createBrandBean.createBrand}" tabindex="5" styleClass="std-btn"
                />

--- >> in my createBrandBean.java File

private BrandVO brand;   // Create a POJO Object

public String createBrand() {

brand.setName("");

or

brand = new BrandVO();

return "SUCCESS";

}

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="loginname" type="text" value="USERNAME" 
       size="10" onFocus="this.value=''"><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

In actionListner you should use

```
txtField.setText("");
```